# Text in responsive image map its areas

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4, imagemap

I have an image map as follows.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <img src="..." style="width: 100%;" usemap="#image-map">

            <map name="image-map">
                <area href="#..." coords="2131,1690,1966,1696,1972,2114,2571,2117,2577,1398,2131,1398" shape="poly">
                <area href="#..." coords="1393,1686,1948,2114" shape="rect">
                <area href="#..." coords="460,1547,460,2120,1291,2120,1288,1572" shape="poly">
                <area href="#..." coords="429,1020,674,1324" shape="rect">
                <area href="#..." coords="686,1020,1334,1321" shape="rect">
                <area href="#..." coords="463,1386,2109,1401,2103,1659,1387,1659,1381,1559,466,1525" shape="poly">
            </map>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I make it responsive so it is shown properly using [Matt Stow's rwdImageMaps JQuery plugin](https://github.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps).

```
<script src="./js/jquery.rwdImageMaps.min.js"></script>
<script>$('img[usemap]').rwdImageMaps();</script>
```

I want to have text displayed on the areas. The reason I don't *hardcode* (1) the text on the image is because I want to change the text depending on the language chosen by the user.

For other elements that need translation, such as a simple `<p>`, I add an attribute `lang-tag` and fetch the relevant translation from a JSON; e.g. `<p lang-tag="hello">Hello, World!</p>`.

How can I achieve the same for the image-map, while keeping the responsiveness?

(1) By *hardcoding* text on an image I mean letting the text be inherent part of the image.

Answer (score 1):

1. Read the image-map coordinates from the DOM `<area>` tags
2. Determine the actual image size
3. Scale the coordinates to match the image size
4. Absolutely-position a DIV with the text at the first pair of coordinates

Comment: Sounds great. I don't think it is necessary to scale the coordinates myself since the Matt Stow plugin will have done that for me already.